# Subsetting shinyTable

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently playing around with `shinyTable` which is a `shiny` compatible implementation of HandsonTable (https://github.com/trestletech/shinyTable). By coincidence I realized, that if I add a `logical` column to the rendered `data.frame` the values will appear as clickable checkboxes. My hope was to use this to easily subset the table:

[image]

```
library(devtools)
# those versions are necessary to let shinyTable work with shiny
install_github( "shiny", "rstudio", ref="fcf963639e4839e5689665c257e7f488c9c34cc0" )
install_github( "shinyTable", "JackStat" )
library(shiny)
library(shinyTable)

runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage( 
    htable( "tbl", clickId="tblClick", headers="provided")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl <- renderHtable({
      if( is.null( input$tbl ) ){
        return( data.frame( select = TRUE, value = 1:10  ) )
      } else{
        return( input$tbl[ input$tbl$select, ] )
      }
    })
  }
))
```

However, when unchecking the check boxes I'll get the following result:

[image]

Is anyone experienced with `shinyTable` and can give me an advice how to avoid this?

**Alternatively:**

Any other (for my users *comfortable*) method which let me create subsettable tables?

Comment: I was using `selectInput(...,multiple=TRUE)` for these kind of subsetting and seemed neater to me

Answer (score 1):

Less is more in this case

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTable)

runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage( 
    htable( "tbl", clickId="tblClick", headers="provided", readOnly = 'false')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl <- renderHtable({
      if( is.null( input$tbl ) ){
        return( data.frame( select = TRUE, value = 1:10  ) )
      }
    })

  }

))
```

Comment: Thanks so far, this indeed avoids this odd behavior. But how do I subset now? It does not even has to be reactive. But there must be at least something like an action button, which removes the unselected rows from the view.