# Data input via shinyTable in R shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

I want to build a shiny app that gets matrix data as input and returns a table based on some operations on it as output. By search I find that ShinyTable package could be useful. I tried below shiny codes but the result app appears gray out and without result.

```
library(shinyTable)
shiny::runApp(list(
  ui=pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('Simple matrixInput')
    ,
    sidebarPanel(
      htable("tbl")
      ,
      submitButton("OK")
    )
    ,
    mainPanel(

      tableOutput(outputId = 'table.output')
    ))
  ,
  server=function(input, output){
    output$table.output <- renderTable({
      input$tbl^2
    }
    , sanitize.text.function = function(x) x 
    )
  }
))
```

**Any Idea?**

Comment: It's is a known issue, it occured with new versions of shiny "because of the way Shiny now handles custom inputs" see : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/F8aAtv85ZGs

Comment: Thanks Julien, Can we be hopeful for solve is?

Comment: Please have look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910853/subsetting-shinytable and the `shiny` and `shinyTable` versions I am using there.

Comment: I tried to install and load both shiny and shinyTable like you, but I got this error: 
"Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : lazy-load database 'P' is corrupt
In addition: Warning message:
In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘shiny’"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `shinyTable` package has been greatly improved in the [`rhandsontable` package](https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable).

Here is a minimal function that takes a data frame and runs a shiny app allowing to edit it and to save it in a `rds` file:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

editTable <- function(DF, outdir=getwd(), outfilename="table"){
  ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Edit and save a table"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        helpText("Shiny app based on an example given in the rhandsontable package.", 
                 "Right-click on the table to delete/insert rows.", 
                 "Double-click on a cell to edit"),

        wellPanel(
          h3("Table options"),
          radioButtons("useType", "Use Data Types", c("TRUE", "FALSE"))
        ),
        br(), 

        wellPanel(
          h3("Save"), 
          actionButton("save", "Save table")
        )        

      ),

      mainPanel(

        rHandsontableOutput("hot")

      )
    )
  ))

  server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    values <- reactiveValues()

    ## Handsontable
    observe({
      if (!is.null(input$hot)) {
        DF = hot_to_r(input$hot)
      } else {
        if (is.null(values[["DF"]]))
          DF <- DF
        else
          DF <- values[["DF"]]
      }
      values[["DF"]] <- DF
    })

    output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
      DF <- values[["DF"]]
      if (!is.null(DF))
        rhandsontable(DF, useTypes = as.logical(input$useType), stretchH = "all")
    })

    ## Save 
    observeEvent(input$save, {
      finalDF <- isolate(values[["DF"]])
      saveRDS(finalDF, file=file.path(outdir, sprintf("%s.rds", outfilename)))
    })

  })

  ## run app 
  runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
  return(invisible())
}
```

For example, take the following data frame:

```
> ( DF <- data.frame(Value = 1:10, Status = TRUE, Name = LETTERS[1:10],
                    Date = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 10),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE) )
   Value Status Name       Date
1      1   TRUE    A 2016-08-15
2      2   TRUE    B 2016-08-16
3      3   TRUE    C 2016-08-17
4      4   TRUE    D 2016-08-18
5      5   TRUE    E 2016-08-19
6      6   TRUE    F 2016-08-20
7      7   TRUE    G 2016-08-21
8      8   TRUE    H 2016-08-22
9      9   TRUE    I 2016-08-23
10    10   TRUE    J 2016-08-24
```

Run the app and have fun (especially with the calendars ^^):

[image]

Edit the *handsontable*:

[image]

Click on the *Save* button. It saves the table in the file `table.rds`. Then read it in R:

```
> readRDS("table.rds")
   Value Status    Name       Date
1   1000  FALSE Mahmoud 2016-01-01
2   2000  FALSE       B 2016-08-16
3      3  FALSE       C 2016-08-17
4      4   TRUE       D 2016-08-18
5      5   TRUE       E 2016-08-19
6      6   TRUE       F 2016-08-20
7      7   TRUE       G 2016-08-21
8      8   TRUE       H 2016-08-22
9      9   TRUE       I 2016-08-23
10    10   TRUE       J 2016-08-24
```

Comment: Hi @Stéphane Laurent : I am new-ish to shiny, I am trying to understand the code within the Observer of your solution, what's the purpose of this code block? If I skip this piece of the code what functionality will I miss?

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for a solution that users can input their matrix data as in excel you could probably take a look at the package "shinySky" and more specifically to its component "Handsontable Input/Output". The relevant web address is: https://github.com/AnalytixWare/ShinySky.

Another similar solution would be the package shinyTable. You can find more information at https://github.com/trestletech/shinyTable

Answer (score 4):

You could use `hotable("matrixTable")` from the [`shinysky` package](https://github.com/AnalytixWare/ShinySky/wiki).

```
library(shiny, shinysky)
shinyApp(
  ui     = shinyUI (wellPanel(hotable("matrixTable"),hotable("resultTable"))),

  server = shinyServer (function(input, output) {
    A = matrix(c(1:6), nrow=2) # init - input matrix A
    output$matrixTable <- renderHotable({data.frame(A)}, readOnly = FALSE)

    R = matrix(rep(0,6), nrow=2) # init - result matrix R
    output$resultTable <- renderHotable({data.frame(R)}, readOnly = TRUE)

    observe({  # process matrix
      df <- hot.to.df(input$matrixTable)
      if(!is.null(df)) {    # ensure data frame from table exists
        B = data.matrix(df) # ensure its numeric
        R = B^2             # some matrix operation
        output$resultTable <- renderHotable({data.frame(R)})
      }
    }) # end of observe
  }) # end of server
)
```

In the user interface `ui` the input `"matrixTable"` and the `"resultTable"` are visualised. The `server` initialises these tables, such that `matrixTable` can be edited. That means you can copy & paste your data from Excel, or change values manually. The `observe` function is activated, whenever a change is noticed in the input `matrixTable`. We extract a data frame `df` with `ho.to.df` from that table. In case its not `NULL` we convert it into a matrix, and apply some matrix operations (e.g. square each element) and return the output as a new matrix.

This solution was obtained by using Christo's suggestion and Stephane's approach.

Comment: Got the warning error package ‘shinysky’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if the following is what you are looking for, but here goes. Assuming that you can input the matrix as a text/csv file, then the following modification to your code above would work. This is directly from the Shiny tutorial: http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#uploads

```
shiny::runApp(list(
    ui=pageWithSidebar(
        headerPanel('Simple matrixInput')
        ,
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
              accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv'))
            ,
            tags$hr(),
            checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
            radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                 c(Comma=',',
                   Semicolon=';',
                   Tab='\t'),
                 'Comma'),
            radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                 c(None='',
                   'Double Quote'='"',
                   'Single Quote'="'"),
                 'Double Quote')
        )
        ,
        mainPanel(

            tableOutput(outputId = 'table.output')
        ))
    ,
    server=function(input, output){
        output$table.output <- renderTable({

        inFile <- input$file1

       if (is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)

        tbl <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, quote=input$quote)
        return(tbl^2)
        })
    }
))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response rmk. I'm no interested in uploading files. I need a solution that users can input their matrix data in a excel like table.