# Shiny: is there a table widget?

Tags: r, shiny

The input of my shiny application would be a table with 2 columns.
In the first column, the user specifies the treatment groups.
In the second column, the user specifies the sample sizes within each group.
There could be as many treatment groups as the user wishes.

Is there a shiny widget that fits this purpose?

```
group   N
placebo 15
trt1    18
trt2    3
trt3    17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package rhandsontable (https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable) is one possibility for implementing an editable / fillable table in Shiny.

For more possibilities, please see the previous thread here at [Data input via shinyTable in R shiny application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272571/data-input-via-shinytable-in-r-shiny-application). Also the aforementioned package's site gives an example for a data file editor at https://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/.

Comment: This does also look really nice. Thanks for showing me this!

Comment: @JTT: Thank you. I will have a look as soon as I can :-)

Answer (score 2):

[`dataTableOutput() / renderDataTable()`](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html) from the [`DT`](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/) package is a good option for all your data table needs in Shiny.

Comment: Using this option, can the user fill in the table??

Comment: @Marco you can customize it in such a way that you can filter the data.table. Then you can find the groups and sample sizes you want (see chapter 2.7 from [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT)). Does that fit your needs? Otherwise you might want to try things out with sliders and/or other user inputs

Comment: OK, thanks! Let me try this out and I will accept your answer afterwards. Thank you again for your input.