# Are table displayed on shiny,read only?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make an app where the user can enter values into a table.

So I created a table using data.frame command and plotted the table on the HTML of the app using regular shiny ui and server codes.

The problem which I face is the table is in "readonly" format, I have no idea how do I read values from such a table plotted on the HTML page of shiny.

Kindly suggest me any changes

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

In native shiny, the `dataTableOutputs` as well as the `tableOutputs` are always readonly. If you want more functionality, you will have to get *additional packages*. Here are two options I know of. Both of them require some legwork.

1. The package [`rhandsontable`](https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable) gives access to EXCEL-like tables that can be altered from the client. With a proper setup, the changed table will be even accessible on the server side. For further reading, I recommend Stéphane Laurents answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272571/data-input-via-shinytable-in-r-shiny-application).
2. The package [`DT`](https://github.com/rstudio/DT) gives you a way of accessing selected rows on the server side. This can be used to implement a "delete rows" feature. For adding rows, you would have to write this yourself with `textInput`s, `selectInput`s etc. but it's fairly straightforward.

Both packages are available through CRAN and GitHub.

I personally prefer option 2 since in most cases, an add row/delete row interface is much saver. If you give your users the posibillity to fill whatever they want in the table, the server will not be happy.

Here is a minimal example to showcase the second approach

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  actionButton("delete_rows", "Delete selected rows"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  serverTable = reactiveVal(mtcars)

  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    serverTable()
  })

  observeEvent(input$delete_rows, {
    serverTable(serverTable()[-input$mytable_rows_selected,])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```