# R, Shiny, DT table, replacing data

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, dt

I'm trying to be able to edit a table through a text input followed by an action button. In addition, I'd like the data to stay changed, so that if I reload the app or enter in new data into the text input, the previous input doesn't revert to the previous value.

I feel like there is likely a simple way to do this, and I see things like this, where we can delete rows: [Are table displayed on shiny,read only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751915/are-table-displayed-on-shiny-read-only) But that wouldn't help for when you reload the app. In addition, I don't seem quite able to apply it to just changing a specific cell.

Below I have some simplified code, using mtcars. I added two columns, one giving a Car number, and one for if the car is good. So essentially, I would like to be able to enter 1, then row Car_number 1 will have Good_car column changed to True. Then, when I enter 2, I'd like for both the previous 1 and now 2 to also be True. And finally, next time I reload the app I want them to still be True.

The second data table  is just showing that I know the dplyr mutate replace can change specific things in a data table, because when I enter the car number using that it will change Good_car to T for that number, until the input changes then it will revert back.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

mtbetter<-mtcars%>%
  mutate(Car_number = c(1:32),
         Good_car = F)


ui <- fluidPage(
      textInput(inputId = "text", label = "Filter Car Number"),
      actionButton("action", "Go!"),
      dataTableOutput(outputId = "table"),
      dataTableOutput(outputId = "table2")
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  mtfinal = reactiveVal(mtbetter)

  output$table<-renderDataTable({
    mtfinal()
    })
  observeEvent(input$action, {mtfinal()%>%
      mutate(Good_car = replace(Good_car, Car_number == input$text, T))})

  output$table2<-renderDataTable({

    mtbetter2<-mtbetter%>%
      mutate(Good_car = replace(Good_car, Car_number == input$text, T))

    mtbetter2

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I also suspect that Replacedata will do it, but admittedly the documentation still can go over my head sometimes: https://rdrr.io/cran/DT/man/replaceData.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really close, all you need to do is modify your `observeEvent`:

```
observeEvent(input$action, {mtfinal(mtfinal()%>%
     mutate(Good_car = replace(Good_car, Car_number == input$text, T)))})
```

Why your solution does not do what you want it to do: You call the value of `mtfinal()` and filter from there. However, you do not write the resulting table back to `mtfinal()`. So the next time you want to update it, you start again with the initial value for `mtfinal()`. Since you can set a new value for a `reactiveVal` called `y` to `x` by doing `y(x)`, all we need to do is wrap the entire statement in `mtfinal(...)`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed!