# How to save edits in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, edit

I want my end users to be able to update and save comments in a table , through shiny (Action button).  If i use the following code , it does open the table, but when i close it , it doesn't save the changes. Here is a sample code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton("Approve", "Click for Approval"),
    tableOutput('edit')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$edit<- eventReactive(input$Approve, 
    sp.1 <-  edit(mpg))


  }
)
```

How do i make it save the changes ?

Comment: Do you want previous users comments to show to users when the app is loaded? Or do you just want output files that are created for your own record?

Comment: ideally yes, but creating for own record would also work

Answer (score 0):

You will need an external file to store the comments, and read and write when needed in Shiny server function.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more or point me to a direction where i can find more information on this ? I am a new to shiny/r

Comment: So the table widget you use is only for displaying a data frame as I saw on RStudio reference... you might want to use DTOutput() from this article: https://blog.rstudio.com/2018/03/29/dt-0-4/.

Comment: u used DTOutput as well, it has the same issue ..it allows me to edit, but it wont let me save it

Comment: this looks like a solution to you problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272571/data-input-via-shinytable-in-r-shiny-application. Basically you will have to save you data somewhere, either a database, or in local file(txt,csv,rds.....I recommend .rds format since its a lot faster.)