# How to import reactive datasets in Rshiny?

Tags: r, dataset, shinydashboard, reactive

i m creating a risk dashboard , the problem is that i need the data set to be reactive , i have a simple dataset composed of countries (8) , sectors and values , what i want is that my app will be able to deal with different data sets for example if we change the colnames (country becomes pays) and we change the position of the col ,the app will recognize the column as country (in reality the data set is composed of an undefined number of variables with unkown names)

for example for the country column , i thought of creating a list that contains all country names and and when the first row of a column matches with a country from that list ,the column become names country

like that the problem is solved for one variable and what about the other ones

Comment: [How's this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272571/data-input-via-shinytable-in-r-shiny-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's unnecesary complexity.

I suggest you to build an script to clean your data first with those specifications and then use it as a source.

You can use pattern recognition to match columns but be sure there aren't similar columns, for example, if you have two numerical variables there's a big problem.

Via Shiny I suggest you:

1. fileInput to import your database
2. Visualizate your database using `DT`
3. Create as many textInput boxes as columns you have
4. Manually change colnames using `dplyr::rename` and the boxes
5. Use the transformed database in your dashboard

Other options can be made using `base::grep` and `dplyr`.